# php подключение переменных из другого файла

Tags: php, html, mysql

Я создаю Вход и Авторизацию.Я почти закончил но возникла такая проблема.Когда я хотел после проверки на существования пользователя чтобы переходил на файл где будет писать "Здравствуйте имя пользователя(взята после входа)".Но нужно было перенести переменую $_POST[log].Я не знаю команды для переноса этой переменой. Помогите пожалуйста.

код Входа:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');// делаем на русском
require_once 'kod.php'; // скрипт с кодом
// подключаемся к серверу
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
if (!$_POST[log]) {//Проверка логина на символы
echo '<p id="A">Вы не вели логин</p>';
}
if (!$_POST[password]) {//Проверка пароля на символы
echo '<p id="A">Вы не вели пароль</p>';
}
else{
 $A1 = $link->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$_POST[log]' AND `password` = '$_POST[password]'");
 $A2 = $A1->fetch_assoc();
 if (count($A2) == 0) {
     echo "<p id='A'>Такого пользавателя не существует</p>";
 }else {
   header('Location: php3.php');
 }
}
mysqli_close($link); //Закрытие
?>
<!--HTML код-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css">
<title>Вход</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <h1>Вход</h1>
    <p>Логин: </p>
    <input type="text" name="log">
    <p>Пароль: </p>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <br /><br /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти">
    <a href="php1.php">Авторизоваться</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Примечание файл CSS.css отвечает за красный текст

код отвечающий за аккаунт:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');// делаем на русском
echo "Здравствуйте";
echo $_POST[log];
?>
```

Comment: Используйте [session](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php). И никогда так не пишите `$_POST[log]`, всегда обрамляйте кавычками `$_POST['log']`.

Comment: как он работает

Comment: Я ссылку дал, там все детально описано. И да, у вас инъекция в `sql` запросе, взломают если так авторизовываться. Используйте [Подготавливаемые запросы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)